# Remove specific variable from list R

Tags: r, list, variables

I want to remove a pre-defined variable from a list in R, for example:

```
vertex <- c("A","B","C","D")    
list_safe<-vertex

z<-sample(list_safe,1)

list_infected[z] <- z

list_safe_new<-list_safe[list_safe =! "z"]
```

Somehow, it does not remove z=C (for example) from the list_safe.
Can someone help me?

Comment: syntax error? Do you mean `list_safe[list_safe != z]`

Comment: You have not defined `list_infected`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define z, so you shouldn't put "z" in your statement.

```
vertex <- c("A","B","C","D")    
list_safe<-vertex

 z <-sample(list_safe,1)

 list_safe_new<-list_safe[list_safe != z]
```